# Memory limit time out on 113MB CSV file how i import

Tags: php, sql, csv

i have a 113 MB csv file i want to import into SQL table however it reaches the windows memory limit of 2GB and stops so setting up memory limit in php ini ll not help
i tried bigdump however it returns numbers of columns in table do not match with number of columns in csv file though i created correct number of columns.
Please help

Comment: How do you try to import your file?

Comment: i hope your using: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: i am trying with phpmyadmin

Comment: not sure what phpmyadmin is using, but i strongly suggest you do it with LOAD DATA INFILE

Comment: i believe LOAD DATA INFILE would not help it reads from text file and i have CSV

Comment: Not enough information. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: closing it after he has accepted an answer - horse, barn door ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

example of using LOAD DATA  for  a csv file ignoring the top line assuming it has the  column names

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'YOUR FILE NAME' INTO TABLE tbl_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```